# Does geolocation prevent mobile navigation apps to open?

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, navigation, geolocation

I am struggling with a problem for some time. I couldn't find any articles with proper help. I am building an website where I have "Navigate" button. That button must find the user location and navigate him to a specific place. If the user uses desktop computer it should open google maps with the route on it. But if the user uses mobile device it should open his navigation app directly and start the route.(Of course if there isn't installed navigation it should also open google maps in browser.)

It turns that finding user geolocation prevents opening the navigation app. Instead it opens google maps in browser. Does anyone know where the problem is and is there any way to achieve my goal.

This is my code using HTML5 geolocation:

```
$('#button-navigate').on('click', function(e){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoNavigate);
    e.preventDefault();
});

function geoNavigate( position ) {
    var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
    var myLng = position.coords.longitude;
    window.location.href = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=' + myLat + ',' + myLng + '&daddr=42.140511,24.6884765';
}
```

But if I try it that way down, with static starting point, without Geolocation function, it seems to work correct:

```
$('#button-navigate').on('click', function(e) {
    window.location.href = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=43.140511,24.6884765&daddr=42.140511,24.6884765';

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I don't like the idea to get the user location on page load and set it as href attribute on the button. Is there any other way to get user coordinates or solution to my geolocation problem?

**Edit**: It seems that it happens on android phones. I have tried iPhone 6 and iPhone 5S and it works correctly.

Comment: `But if the user uses mobile device it should open his navigation app directly and start the route` I don't have navigation app on my mobile

Comment: In this case it should also open google maps in browser.